# Noether current for self-dual Yang-Mills theory

Tags: homework-and-exercises, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem, yang-mills

The Lagrangian for self-dual Yang-Mills theory, in spinorial notations is given by

$$\mathcal{L}= B^{a\, AB} (\partial_{A}{}^{A'} A^a_{A'B} + f^{abc} A^b_{A}{}^{A'} A^c_{A'B})$$

where $B^{a\,AB}$ is a self-dual auxiliary field and $A^{a\,AA'}$ is the gauge connection. We consider transformation of the gauge field as shifts, i.e $\delta A^{a\,AA'}=\epsilon A^{a\,AA'}$ such that the connection is left self-dual. Let us compute the change in the Lagrangian.

$\delta \mathcal{L}= B^{a\, AB} (\partial_{A}{}^{A'}\delta A^a_{A'B} +f^{abc} A^b_{A}{}^{A'}\delta A^c_{A'B}+f^{abc} \delta A^b_{A}{}^{A'} A^c_{A'B})\\
=\epsilon B^{a\, AB}F^a_{AB}=0\\$

where in the last line, we used the fact that the shift of the connection leaves the connection self-dual and thus satisfies $F^a_{AB}=0$. How to compute the conserved current in this case?

Comment: The Noether current for all symmetries are evaluated by elevating the global parameter to a function $ \epsilon \to \epsilon(x)$. The action then changes as $S \to S + \int \partial_\mu \epsilon J^\mu$. The coefficient $J^\mu$ is the Noether current.

Comment: Can you please outline the process in spinor notations? I am getting stuck while doing this in spinor notations and this is the problem.

Comment: Before finding the Noether current, can you prove that this is indeed a symmetry? Put that calculation into the question please and we can proceed from there.

Comment: I have put the calculation that shifts of the connection such that the connection is left self-dual is a symmetry.